# паттерн «Репозиторий» и entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, архитектура, repository

Изучая различные статьи и дискуссии я пришел к выводу, что реализация этого паттерна излишня так как  сам EF «реализует его и в итоге это выльется в надстраивание абстракции над абстракцией, но я так и не смог найти примера того как уровень доступа к данным должен реализовываться правильно. К примеру есть туториал:
http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.7.php
Был бы очень благодарен за небольшое описание того как бы этот пример выглядел без реализации вышеупомянутого паттерна.

Comment: не знаю актуально ли еще. у себя в приложении я использую *контекст* в слое бизнес логики, *gui* же видит только слой бизнес логики.